# Do sections of a family of curves have affine neighborhoods?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X\rightarrow S$ be a proper smooth morphism of schemes of relative dimension 1, where $S = Spec\; R$  for some ring $R$. Let $g : S\rightarrow X$ be a section. Does there exist an affine scheme $U\subset X$ which contains the image $g(S)$?

We can embed $X$ inside $\mathbb{P}^n_R$ for some $n$, in which case the section $g$ just corresponds to the "point" $x_0 = r_0,\ldots,x_n = r_n$. If for some $i$, $r_i\in R^\times$, then we can just set $U$ to be the affine open of $\mathbb{P}^n$ where $x_i\ne 0$, though a priori theres no reason why the $r_i$'s couldn't all be nonunits.

What if I further assume that $g^*\Omega_{X/S}$ is trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a place Grothendieck's view is superior. We have $\mathbb{P}^n_R$ and a section $Y\subset \mathbb{P}^n_R$ to the map $\pi:\mathbb{P}^n_R\to R$ (I write $R$ instead of $\mathrm{Spec}\, R$.). Grothendieck says, this is equivalent to giving a surjection $R^{n+1}\to L$, where $L$ is a locally free sheaf on $R$ of rank one. Let $Q$ be the kernel and so this sequence splits to give $R^{n+1}=Q\oplus L$. Consider the projection to $Q$. This gives an embedding of $Z=\mathbb{P}_R(Q)\subset\mathbb{P}^n_R$. It is easy to check that $Z$ does not intersect $Y$ and complement of $Z$ is affine.

Comment: Here by $\mathbb{P}_R(Q)$ you are referring to a "projective bundle" right? I'm very new to these things. How would you check that the complement of $Z$ is affine? (I get the feeling that $Z$ not intersecting $Y$ probably follows from unraveling the definitions)

Comment: The map from the complement to $R$ is a locally trivial $\mathbb{A}^n$ bundle.